# Wireless problems on HP

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hardware

I'm not able to enable Wireless using the hardware switch on my HP ProBook4430s.

Because of this the **Enable Wireless** option is greyd out and I cannot enable it.

The greyd out option can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

The results of  **iwconfig**  for my system are as follows,

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Also I tried to do the following,

```
    sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

but I got an error as below,

```
    SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Also the result of  **sudo rfkill list all**  for my system is as follows,

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

How do I fix this problem?

Thanku!

Comment: Try posting the results of iwconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

Then

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

And report, by editing again your post, if there are errors.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But the problem is still existing! And I edited my post as you said. Please do the needfull. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Try when booting your computer:

1. press f2? to get into bios
2. press f9? to reset to default settings
3. press f10? to save settings

Check if you're still hard blocked.

[keys are for my laptop which isn't a dell]

Comment: this is probably the best answer around. got stuck with HardBlocked: yes, for some reason WiFi adapter has been disabled, and WiFi Hard Key (HP ProBook 6560b) didn't work since there are no default mapping in linux for it.